# Why can't I create an integer by passing in a pointer?

Tags: c, pointers

Seems trivial, but I can't understand why this doesn't work.

```
int main(void){
    int *k = NULL;
    foo(k);
    printf("%p\n", k);
    printf("%d\n", *k);
    return 0;
}

void foo(int *i){
    i = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (i == NULL){
        printf("memory fail\n");
    }else {
        *i = 10;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
(nil)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I'm guessing it's because I'm passing in NULL, rather than the address of `k`, but unsure how to pass the address of `k` in.

Comment: did you declare foo above main first?

Comment: Yes, and including the `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the pointer by value. So the allocated value of the pointer does not come back to the caller. Use double indirection instead. For example,

```
void foo(int **i){
    *i = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (*i == NULL){
        printf("memory fail\n");
    }else {
        **i = 10;
    }
}
int main(void){
    int *k = NULL;
    foo(&k);
    printf("%p\n", k);
    printf("%d\n", *k);
    return 0;
}
```

This will have address of k passed as value and you get k back because of the double indirection.